# How to print any variable in FreeMarker?

Tags: freemarker

I have a `Map<String, Object>` which contains Strings, Doubles, Integers, Booleans and `null` (missing) as values. I want to print out the value in a FreeMarker template.

When I use `${data[field]!?html}` it works for all other variables, but crashes on Boolean with:

```
freemarker.core._MiscTemplateException: Can't convert boolean to string automatically, because the "boolean_format" setting was "true,false", which is the legacy default computer-language format, and hence isn't accepted.
```

The application is an administration UI, where I don't that much care about the exact formatting, but I'd prefer booleans to use the standard `true` and `false`.  (The `boolean_format` flag controls standard formatting of booleans, but using `true` and `false` seems to be [explicitly prohibited](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_setting.html#autoid_117) for some mind-boggling reason.)

What's the best way to work around the FreeMarker prohibitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to achieve this is to use the `?string` method:  `${data[field]!?string?html}`

This was mentioned only in the [`Configurable` JavaDoc](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/core/Configurable.html#setBooleanFormat-java.lang.String-), and the `?string` method [is deprecated](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_boolean.html#ref_builtin_string_for_boolean). I hope it's not going away anytime soone.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from FreeMarker 2.3.29 you can set the `boolean_format` configuration setting to `c`, which will format booleans as `?c` would, to `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting boolean format to `true,false` is hard-coded disabled in freemarker configuring.
I'm using this trick to make it available. (a sample used in spring configurer)

```
public freemarker.template.Configuration createConfiguration() throws IOException, TemplateException {
    freemarker.template.Configuration configuration = super.createConfiguration();
    configuration.setBooleanFormat("anything,anything");
    // a hack to set boolean_format to "true,false" (it's hard-coded disabled in freemarker configuring)
    try {
        FieldUtils.writeField(configuration, "trueStringValue", "true", true);
        FieldUtils.writeField(configuration, "falseStringValue", "false", true);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ignored) {
    }
    return configuration;
}
```